# Why has Ubuntu 20.04 locked me out of a whole partition that has nothing to do with the os and how do I reclaim ownership of partition/drive?

Tags: partitioning, permissions

Ubuntu has locked me out of a separate partition outside of the system, it just holds my stuff sys ntfs so windows also has access. I only have read permission, I need to get it back. How do I reclaim ownership with all permissions? I saved stuff there just the other day, so it just happened I don't know how or why.

Comment: You've provided no clues on how you mounted, if you mounted RW or RO, if it was RW, it'll flip to RO on certain conditions such as unclean *file-system* (eg. fastboot) or errors (see Nmath's prior comment, or your system logs if you mounted via GUI for the reason/cause, if you mounted via terminal the messages show at mount time).

Comment: Could not save the file “/mnt/My-Stuff/Untitled Document 1”. you are trying to save to a read only disk. There is no fastboot was mounted using disks app. I have been using the drive for a long time with same setup and never had any problem.

Comment: Windows updates turn fast start up on. Or Windows/NTFS file corruption will also prevent the Linux NTFS driver from mounting NTFS partition as read/write. You may need to double check if fast start up or hibernation was turned on or run chkdsk from Windows on the NTFS partition.